# Download and parse a JSON with swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

Can't figure out why this don't work...
when i run it, i have this error in the console:

```
[CONNECTION] OK, data correctly downloaded
[ERROR] An error has happened with parsing of json data
nil
```

maybe is the JSON format in the link that i pass in the `salvaJson()` function.

This is the viewController:

```
//MARK:proprietà
@IBOutlet weak var meteoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descrizioneLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let data = salvaJson()

        let json = json_parseData(data!)

        print(json)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func salvaJson()->NSData?{
    guard let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.medialweb.it/corsi_ok.json") else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {
        print("[ERROR] There is an unspecified error with the connection")
        return nil
    }
    print("[CONNECTION] OK, data correctly downloaded")
    return data
}


// funzione per la generazione del json a partire da un NSData
func json_parseData(data: NSData) -> NSDictionary? {
    do {
        let json: AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
        print("[JSON] OK!")
        return (json as? NSDictionary)
    } catch _ {
        print("[ERROR] An error has happened with parsing of json data")
        return nil
    }
}
```

I have removed the comment at the top o JSON. `json_parseData()` 
Now print:[JSON] OK! but i still have `nil` instead of the printend json

Comment: What is the output of `print(json)`?

Comment: The JSON seems to start with text commented like a in a code file. Also, since you did a do/catch, print the error instead of just a text. The error may give you the real reason (there are more than one reason to fail).

Comment: the print(json) output is nil

Comment: how can i print the error?

Comment: @MatteoVilla your json format not correct format so  unable to parse json and json set  nil

Comment: @MatteoVilla this the your error and check my update section .Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
nil

Comment: You have changed the URL in your question. Now the new one returns an array of dictionaries, you will have to adapt to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem is your JSON cause json result must be start with array**

I tested your code it is working code :

```
guard let url = NSURL(string: "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/") else {
            return nil
        }
```

[Pokemon Webapi](https://pokeapi.co)  and   [test your json format](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

**UPDATE :**

> how can i print the error?

```
     do {
            let json: AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
            print("[JSON] OK!")
            return (json as? NSDictionary)
        } catch {
            //print("[ERROR] An error has happened with parsing of json data")
            print("\(error)")
            return nil
        }
```

Comment: why if i put the json you use in with pokemon api into the test JSON page it gave me this error: Error:Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.[Code 29, Structure 0]

Comment: the code with this json work fine but the validator give me that error

Comment: go to https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1 and copy all then go to  https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and past your json . i hope you will get success

Comment: ok, if i copy paste the json it validate . else if i paste the url it give me the error i write in the comment above.

Comment: i removed the comment line but still have error with this json:     http://www.medialweb.it/v_prenotazioni_workshop.json

Comment: do you think your json is valid format ? if so how?

Comment: now your json format  http://www.medialweb.it/corsi_ok.json is  vaild . do you get any error ?if so what is that ?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON doesn't seem to be valid. [Here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) you can find a JSON validator that fails with the URL you have.

Answer (score 1):

agree with Above, you have to make sure your JSON data is in valid format. Try to remove these lines in your JSON data

```
/**
Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin
@version 0.1
*/

// Database 'convegnoagi2016_it_db'

// convegnoagi2016_it_db.v_prenotazioni_workshop
```